# Files Instrumented by LDRA are not returning back to un-instrumented state

Tags: dynamic-analysis, ldra

I am using LDRA to instrument files and run dynamic analysis. I know that internally LDRA modifies the source files and adds some variables to keep track of the number of statements executed.
Once dynamic analysis is done, I am trying to compile the code for normal runs, but I can see that builds are failing due to un-resolved variable. These variables are added by LDRA for dynamic analysis.
How do I clear these variables and have a clean build.

Comment: The instrumented code is a copy of the original... the original is not changed?

Comment: I get down-voted if I suggest contacting support@ldra.com (which you'll be paying for), but I suspect we need a bit more info to help answer this question.  eg which variables are being unresolved? *Note profile for association*